# Laravel Push Notifications, non static method called statically

Tags: php, ios, laravel-5, push-notification

I am trying to implement [this](https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification) library for sending push notifications to `iOS` app. All my configurations are fine. When I tested the code snippet available at this page like this:

```
PushNotification::app('appNameIOS')
                ->to($deviceToken)
                ->send('Hello World, i`m a push message');
```

It threw this error:

> Non-static method
>   Davibennun\LaravelPushNotification\PushNotification::Message() should
>   not be called statically

Rightly so, because when I opened the class, there was no such static method. There is one but that is not static. What am I doing wrong? Any help?

**Edit 1**
I have generated config file:

```
return array(

    'hasalty_ios'     => array(
        'environment' =>'development',
        'certificate' =>base_path('pem.p12'),
        'passPhrase'  =>'',
        'service'     =>'apns'
    ),
    'hasalty_android' => array(
        'environment' =>'production',
        'apiKey'      =>'yourAPIKey',
        'service'     =>'gcm'
    )

);
```

**Edit 2**

[image]

My `Laravel` version is `5.5.31`.

Comment: Have you added the PushNotification facade to config/app.php?

Comment: And can you post your use statements please?

Comment: yes i have added that in app.php

Comment: @AaronFahey this is my use statement `use Davibennun\LaravelPushNotification\PushNotification;`

Comment: Try what the latest answer says - look here for more info https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification/issues/67

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you configure the library correctly, you should use

```
use Pushnotification;
```

instead of

```
use Davibennun\LaravelPushNotification\PushNotification;
```

> When a user references any static method on the Cache facade, Laravel resolves the cache binding from the service container and runs the requested method (in this case, get) against that object.
>   [How Facades Work](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/facades#how-facades-work)

**Edit**

You must generate the config file before you use it:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Davibennun\LaravelPushNotification\LaravelPushNotificationServiceProvider" --tag="config"
```

Comment: Great, it solved my this problem but there is another issue now, and that is `Class 'Sly\NotificationPusher\Adapter\' not found`.

Comment: Have you generated the config file? `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Davibennun\LaravelPushNotification\LaravelPushNotificationServiceProvider" --tag="config"`

Comment: I have added the generated file code in my question. Please have a look

Comment: Did you use the correct array index defined in the config flle?

Comment: If you are talking about using the correct app name defined in the config file as `hasalty_ios`, yeah I have.

Comment: Okay, my guess is composer did not work correctly while you install the package. Please check the directory under `vendor` where the package installed.

Comment: I have added the screen shot of the dir structure in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150937/discussion-between-michael-chen-and-saani).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

Change here `use Pushnotification` instead 
of `use Davibennun\LaravelPushNotification\PushNotification;`

[image]